# Potential infinite loop: exceeded 10001 iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a block of by project here in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lewin-mlvmh?file=/src/store/modules/Site.js) where I've used `cherrio, https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, axios` and manual built function to check for pagination, navigate to the next page and **scrape** the data and finally push the **scraped** data into the array of object.

The code somewhat works but gets stuck in the infinite loop while pushing the objects to the array.

The code is successful in scraping and pushing the data of the first page but gets stuck in infinite loop on other pages from pagination. Additionally The code does get in infinite loop if the url with no pagination is given.

Can anyone help me out to my mistake, it's been around a week that I've been trying to resolve this error.

Type `Teacher` for no pagination url and `manager` for pagination url.

Files to look at: `src/store/modules/Site.js`

Files to look at: `src/store/modules/Helpers.js`

Comment: Code that is necessary to understand your question must be pasted into the question itself and formatted appropriately.  Having only external links is not sufficient.  This is because external links tend to break or change over time rendering the question useless as a long term reference to others.  It also messes with search and makes it more difficult for people on mobile to participate.  Please put the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 3):

The bug appears to be in `makeObject()`, shown below:

```js
const makeObject = (jobs, img, org) => {
  let mjobs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    jobs.push({        // FIXME: Pushing into `jobs` which is being iterated
      title: jobs[i],
      img: "https://merojob.com" + img[i],
      org: org[i]
    });
  }
  return mjobs;
}
```

The `for`-loop iterates `jobs`, while pushing new objects into it. The termination condition checks that `i` is less than `jobs.length`, which is being incremented on each iteration, so it never exits the loop.

I think you meant to push into `mjobs` inside the `for`-loop.

Comment: thanks man, that was a silly typo mistake that I didn't notice. Huge thanks man.

Comment: The array data of `forState= makeObject(jobTitles, imgs, orgsNames, locations);` is being overwritten in every iteration. Is there any way I can overcome it ? If there are multiple pages previously pushed data are replaced by the data from current page.